# Plotting a segmented line with segments coloured based on a variable

Tags: c, r, fortran, gnuplot

I'm trying to draw a plot (in R or gnuplot) where the x axis represent a single sample and the y axis is segmented to represented different portions of time. Each line segment (or box) would be coloured depending on a third variable (yes, no, or unknown)

```
SampleID   y1    y1(answer) y2        y2(answer)  y3      y3(answer) 
Sample 1   0-50  yes        51-60     no          61-85   yes
Sample 2   0-40  yes        41-60     no          61-86   no
Sample 3   0-45  unknown    46-69     yes         70-85   unknown
```

where colour for yes=green, no=red; and unknown=grey

Can anyone suggest a solution? I keep running in to the same problem, which is that assigning colour based on a third variable for a segment causes difficulty.

Some other forum users seem to be running in to the same problem but as yet I haven't seen an easy workaround. Most suggest doing multiple plots and overlaying them. I wonder if there is some way of rethinking the problem, or reformatting the data that might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but this was my best guess.  (Actually I guess you want to flip the x and y axes, but this should give you a good start.)

Data:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
SampleID   y1    y1(answer) y2        y2(answer)  y3      y3(answer) 
Sample_1   0-50  yes        51-60     no          61-85   yes
Sample_2   0-40  yes        41-60     no          61-86   no
Sample_3   0-45  unknown    46-69     yes         70-85   unknown",
header=TRUE)
```

Rearrange data to long format:

```
library(reshape2)
dd2 <- melt(dd,id.var=1)
dd2 <- transform(dd2,
                 var2=substr(as.character(variable),1,2),
                 type=ifelse(grepl("\\.",as.character(variable)),"answer","range"))
dd2 <- subset(dd2,select=-variable)
dd3 <- dcast(dd2,SampleID+var2~type)
library("stringr")
dd3 <- transform(dd3,start=as.numeric(str_extract(range,"^[0-9]+")),
                 end=as.numeric(str_extract(range,"[0-9]+$")),
                 answer=factor(answer,levels=c("yes","no","unknown")))
```

Picture:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(dd3)+
    geom_segment(aes(x=start,xend=end,y=SampleID,yend=SampleID,colour=answer))+
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("red","green","gray"))+
    theme_bw()
```

You could probably do the last bit with `segments()` as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is a great help.